# How to sort GPS points in clockwise direction (non convex shape!)

Tags: sorting, geometry, gps, racing

[image: Track]

I am generating a racing line for a track shown in the figure. However, I only have the unordered points for the boundaries. How should I sort all these GPS points in a clockwise direction that the vehicle can track?

Same goal as the problem [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67735537/how-to-sort-coordinates-in-python-in-a-clockwise-direction), however with a highly non-convex shape.

```
def rotational_sort(list_of_xy_coords):
    cx, cy = list_of_xy_coords.mean(0)
    x, y = list_of_xy_coords.T
    angles = np.arctan2(x-cx, y-cy)
    indices = np.argsort(angles)
    return list_of_xy_coords[indices]
```

doesn't work

Comment: Given that your points are relatively dense, maybe you could sort by the next closest point?  That is, pick a point nearest the start, find two points nearest that point, measure the difference, pick the one that's the direction you want (+/- x, +/- y), and now you have your next point.  Find the next closest point that isn't the previous, and now you have the next.  This might not work for super tight/poorly sampled corners.

Comment: You may triangulate your points-cloud by [Marching Cubes algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Marching_cubes) (not a Delaunay triangulation). Then pick the segments in the boundary and set circumferences between them.