# Arranging the points in clockwise manner viewing from from surface

Tags: python, arrays, sorting

I have 3d points from the surface. So corresponding to one normal vector they becomes 2d point. That normal vector is anything , standard x,y or z or any other. How can I arrange the points in clockwise direction.
I cannot find out any logic. Sorry for that. Please help

Comment: I think you can find the answer in this link. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41855695/sorting-list-of-two-dimensional-coordinates-by-clockwise-angle-using-python

Comment: it is only for z normal vector. I tried that one. but what if my normal vector will be x or y or any other?